# Getting the wrong element in click handler with overlapping "circle" divs

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying dynamically add HTML elements with click handlers. When the click handler is activated it targets wrong element(it always target the outer circle). Where could be the problem?

```js
(function() {

  //selector, jQuery style
  var $ = function(selector) {
    return document.querySelector(selector);
  }

  //getting quantity of circles
  var quantity = $('.circles').getAttribute('quantity');

  //setting outer width/height for circles
  $('.circles').style.width = (quantity * 50) + 4 + 'px';
  $('.circles').style.height = (quantity * 50) + 4 + 'px';

  //creating element for children
  var childCircle = document.createElement('div');
  childCircle.className = 'subCircle';

  //click function for children
  function onClick() {
    this.attributes.style.value += 'border-color: red;'
    alert(this.clientHeight);
  }

  //append sub circles
  for (var i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
    $('.circles').appendChild(childCircle.cloneNode());
  }

  //iterate over .circles .subCircle and add onClick function for each subCircle and css aswell

  var subCircle = $('.circles').getElementsByClassName('subCircle');
  for (var i = 0; i < subCircle.length; i++) {
    subCircle[i].onclick = onClick;
    subCircle[i].style.width = ((i + 1) * 50) + 'px';
    subCircle[i].style.height = ((i + 1) * 50) + 'px';
  }

})();
```

```css
.circles {
  position: absolute;
}

.subCircle {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  border: 2px solid black;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="circles" quantity=10></div>
</body>
```

Also on jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/martin_borman/1srkL5bf/

Comment: `subCircle[i].onclick = onClick`, you lost the `this` there. Not dot, no `this`.

Comment: make your event listeners like `function(e){e.target.attributes.style.value += 'border-color: red;'}`

Comment: @elclanrs: That's fine with the above, `this `will be set by the call.

Comment: It's not the problem, but `this.attributes.style.value += 'border-color: red;'` **really** should be `this.style.borderColor = 'red;'`

Comment: The problem is not with `this`, but with how you positioned the elements. The biggest circle is on top of all the others, hence it receives all the pointer events. But reversing the order wouldn't help that much since the elements still overlap.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, ah right, the event will.

Comment: you should not use `this` in functions. javascript may confuse as this could mean the function object.

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy: That's just wrong. `this` will never refer to the function itself unless *explicitly* set so. `this` is not some unpredictable variable that should be avoided, it should be *understood* instead. In the above example it is very clear what its value will be.

Comment: This was an absolutely **great** first question. Nice one. All the necessary code, very little if any *unnecessary* code, a fairly clear statement what was wrong. (Remember the Stack Snippets thing for next time, but that's not a detraction.)

Comment: Even though you have a great example, describing the issue with words is very important too. E.g. you could have added that it will always target the outer circle, no matter which one you clicked. The term "wrong element" is meaningless if we don't now what the right element is supposed to be.

Comment: Agree with @FelixKling, that bit did take a little bit more figuring out than was ideal. But for a first question, top marks.

Comment: @Redu: Not only is that unnecessary, but in many cases (not this case), it would actually be a problem. Consider if you're handling a click on a div filled with spans. `e.target` will be the span that was clicked, not the div, which will be `this` (and `e.currentTarget`).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thank you for pointing out. Very good point. I guess i have to correct it like  `function(e){this.attributes.style.borderColor = "red";}` so that in case nested elements are clicked, bubbling will take the `this` all the way up to the element in which the event listener of interest (`click` in this case) is inserted.

Comment: @Redu: *If* the handler is attached elsewhere in the hierarchy, yeah. (Or again, `e.currentTarget` is always the element the event is being dispatched to, regardless of where it started.)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder `e.currentTarget` wasn't something that i was really aware of. I just looked it up and thanks to you i am a little more knowledgeable now. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't `this`, which is actually getting set by the event callback mechanism just fine. It's that your largest circle is on top.

Changing the loop that sets the size lets you put the smaller circles on top:

```
for (var i = 0; i < subCircle.length; i++) {
  subCircle[i].onclick = onClick;
  subCircle[i].style.width = ((subCircle.length - i) * 50) + 'px';
  subCircle[i].style.height = ((subCircle.length - i) * 50) + 'px';
}
```

The key bit there is `(subCircle.length - i) * 50` rather than `(i + 1) * 50`.

I'd also use

```
this.style.borderColor = 'red';
```

rather than

```
this.attributes.style.value += 'border-color: red;'
```

Example:

```js
(function() {

  //selector, jQuery style
  var $ = function(selector) {
    return document.querySelector(selector);
  }

  //getting quantity of circles
  var quantity = $('.circles').getAttribute('quantity');

  //setting outer width/height for circles
  $('.circles').style.width = (quantity * 50) + 4 + 'px';
  $('.circles').style.height = (quantity * 50) + 4 + 'px';

  //creating element for children
  var childCircle = document.createElement('div');
  childCircle.className = 'subCircle';

  //click function for children
  function onClick() {
    this.style.borderColor = 'red';
    alert(this.clientHeight);
  }

  //append sub circles
  for (var i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
    $('.circles').appendChild(childCircle.cloneNode());
  }

  //iterate over .circles .subCircle and add onClick function for each subCircle and css aswell

  var subCircle = $('.circles').getElementsByClassName('subCircle');
  for (var i = 0; i < subCircle.length; i++) {
    subCircle[i].onclick = onClick;
    subCircle[i].style.width = ((subCircle.length - i) * 50) + 'px';
    subCircle[i].style.height = ((subCircle.length - i) * 50) + 'px';
  }

})();
```

```css
.circles {
  position: absolute;
}

.subCircle {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  border: 2px solid black;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="circles" quantity=10></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ha, so it does work, nice! I got confused by the fact that the developer tools will highlight a rectangle when hovering over the elements and assumed there will still be issues because of overlap. It's still early for me...

Comment: @FelixKling: Yeah. Not so much reversing them as just making sure the smallest was on top. I kept staring at that code and saying "There's no way `this` is wrong." and that made me think: What if it's *right*? What *else* could it be? And fairly quickly "the largest element is on top" came from my hindbrain. What took me a while was figuring out why we weren't seeing `click` on the others. Then I realized, doh, they're all siblings, bubbling is irrelevant.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thats it! I totally forgot about layers. Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the z-index property for each circle

```
subCircle[i].style['z-index'] = subCircle.length-i;
```

Actually the larger circle is overlapping all the inner circle.